# How can I calculate decoupling capacitor value?

Tags: decoupling-capacitor

How can I calculate decoupling capacitor value? Which amount of noise we can filter use it. Why use here 10 µF, 0.1 µF capacitor?

[image]

Comment: most likely "because the IC datasheet says so"

Comment: Is your symbol correct? Usually `Vdd` and `Vss` would be positive supply and ground respectively.

Comment: @Colin__s checked the datasheet, turns out it says Vs in there, not Vss, meaning Supply Voltage. OP, you should totally fix that symbol, it's confusing. :)

Comment: Also, a quick Eagle tip: If you want to write signals as negated, you could write them prefixed with a `!`, such as `!CS`. If you say want to negate only a part of it, you can quit negation with another `!` such as `!IO!/MEM`.

Comment: Another quick Eagle tip: If you want to have multiple pins named the same in a part, add `@somerandomnumber` at the end, such as `NC@0` and `NC@1`. The part of the name after the `@` would be invisible in the schematic.

Comment: If you want fairly detailed tutorial on the subject, Dave Jones did a good one on [EEVblog #859](https://youtu.be/BcJ6UdDx1vg)

Answer (score 2):

It's not for amount of noise. It's to supply current (the big one) and to react quickly (the small ones). So to size the big- consider current. Analog circuits, like sensors and stuff, would want 1uF and more. Digital- depends, but normally you put 0.1uF on each VCC input. For really fast stuff it would also be 1nF for low ESL.

In most cases you will not feel a difference. When you will, it will take long hours to understand why the hell your circuit behaves weird way.

Answer (score 1):

Suppose you have 1 amp surges, every 1 microsecond.  What size Cbypass to use?

What if the 1 amp surge exists for 1 nanosecond. What amount is charge is consumed during that 1 nanosecond? \$Q = C V = I T\$

\$Q = I T\$

Q = 1 amp * 1 ns = 1 nanocoulomb

So what? Can your circuit tolerate 1 millivolt of VDD sag?

\$C V = Q\$

\$C = Q / V\$ = 1 nanocoulomb / 1 millivolts = 1 microfarad.

Rinse the math, bring in your own assumptions, and repeat the math.

Comment: You've got _V_ and _Q_ backwards in a derived formula. It should be _C = Q / V_ instead.